# How does VTK implement model error detection and repair?

Tags: 3d, vtk

How does VTK implement model error detection and repair?

I want to implement the function that is checking:
`bad edges`、`holes`、`Bad triangle`（including `bad orientation`、`intersections`、`Overlap`）and repairing them.

How does VTK do it?

Comment: Or is there any method to solve this problem？I use C++. And the model is stl.

Answer (score 0):

VTK does not comes with such functions as far as I know. Error detection is a hard problem, partly because the definition of error may vary depending on the domain. Having a bad number of points in a cell or and in-existing one is of course always wrong, but the few examples you give (bad orientation, intersections or overlap) may be valid in some cases (klein bottle mesh for example).
You can find a manifold checker in [TTK](https://github.com/topology-tool-kit/ttk) that will check the neighborhood of each point / cell is not degenerated. (TTK is a VTK module, so it will work with VTK data set, however it expects a triangulation / tetrahedral mesh).
I am not aware of a good tool that would check for self-intersecting meshes.